# x,y,z to vector offset

Tags: c++, math, vector, imagemagick

I know this may sound stupid but I'm goin crazy with this XD

I'm loading ad image (with ImageMagick) into a 1D vector, so that I have something like:

```
012345678...
RGBRGBRGB...
```

Where 0-. Are obviously the indexes of the vector, and R, G, and B are respectively the red byte, green byte, and blue byte.
So I have a `WIDTHxHEIGHTx3` bytes vector.

Now, let's say I want to access the x,y,z byte, where z is the index of the color, which is the transformation formula to have a linear offset into the vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression produces an index to color component **z** at pixel **(x,y)**:

`((y * WIDTH) + x) * 3 + z`

Assumptions are:

- Data is placed in *row-major order*.
- No padding/alignment bytes are used between rows.

Comment: I'm after the same thing but my vector has width of 12 and hight of 4 and is of type GLfloat. Is the concept similar?

Comment: @QuantumKarl: yes, it would work with your array as well. just make sure your pixels have a 3 channel format like GL_RGB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is stored as a series of rows (not a crazy assumption), you can find byte x,y,z at `y*WIDTH*3 + 3*x + z`